# Middle Button on ThinkPad Not Working with 10.10 update

Tags: 10.10, mouse, thinkpad, lenovo

I have a lenovo thinkpad and the center scrolling button isn't working with the trackpoint anymore... it worked in prior versions of Ubuntu with GPointing Device Settings, but not with 10.10.

Now, it works when I log in, but if i close the lid to my laptop and reopen it, it no longer works. I have to log out then back in. also, i can not uninstall GPointing Device Settings and reinstall because of this error:

> There seems to be a programming error
>   in aptdaemon, the software that allows
>   you to install/remove software and to
>   perform other package management
>   related tasks. Please report this
>   error at
>   http://launchpad.net/aptdaemon/+filebug
>   and retry.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker.py", line 768, in simulate
    return self._simulate_helper(trans, status_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker.py", line 936, in _simulate_helper
    return depends, status, self._cache.required_download, \
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 218, in required_download
    pm.get_archives(fetcher, self._list, self._records)
SystemError: E:I wasn't able to locate file for the linux-image-2.6.32-24-generic-pae package. This might mean you need to manually fix this package.
```

Any ideas? Also, the center click is working like clicking the center of a scroll button it seems. Like, in Chrome, clicking a link opens it in a new tab, etc. How can i fix this?!

===HOW I FIXED IT===
As per the answer i checked as correct i did the following steps in Ubuntu 10.10 and it seemed to work.

First: Go to (in terminal)

```
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d
```

Next: create a file named (as root)

```
20-thinkpad.conf
```

Next: Add the following to the file:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier  "Trackpoint Wheel Emulation"
    MatchProduct    "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint|DualPoint Stick|Synaptics Inc. Composite TouchPad / TrackPoint|ThinkPad USB Keyboard with TrackPoint|USB Trackpoint pointing device|Composite TouchPad / TrackPoint"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Option      "EmulateWheel"      "true"
    Option      "EmulateWheelButton"    "2"
    Option      "Emulate3Buttons"   "false"
    Option      "XAxisMapping"      "6 7"
    Option      "YAxisMapping"      "4 5"
EndSection
```

Next: Save the file

Lastly: Reboot your computer! (or manually save and reboot Xorg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check ThinkWiki's page for instructions on [how to configure TrackPoint scrolling](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_configure_the_TrackPoint#Scrolling).

Answer (score 1):

For people searching through the answers: this applies to Dell's DualPoint Stick as well, for this use the following xorg.conf-snippet:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier      "Scroll w/ DualPoint Stick"
    MatchIsPointer  "on"
    MatchProduct    "DualPoint Stick"
    Option          "EmulateWheel" "on"
    Option          "EmulateWheelButton" "2"
    Option          "EmulateWheelTimeout" "200"
    Option          "XAxisMapping" "6 7"
    Option          "YAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install gpointing-device-settings
```

System > Preferences > Pointing devices

select TrackPoint on left hand side:

- check "Use Wheel emulation"
- in button dropdown menu select '2'
- click OK

Should work now try it out. or follow the link jumpnett posted

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to fix your problem, but the best place to ask is our bug tracker. If this is your first Ubuntu bug, check out [Reporting Ubuntu Bugs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) for easy instructions.