# ThinkPad TrackPoint Buttons Not Working Well

Tags: 11.04, mouse, settings, thinkpad, trackpad

The TrackPoint itself works fine. But the three buttons below the spacebar don't. For example if I were to copy these lines, 1-10, using trackpoint buttons it'd start highlighting at 7. If I use the main TrackPad (the part every laptop) and it's buttons it works normal, 1-10:

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

It's like the button doesn't register right away. I use the TrackPoint ALL the time. I love it and I don't think I can go back to the normal TrackPad, so is there anyway to fix this? An app or setting?

Also, the middle button to scroll isn't working at all I tried:

[Middle Button on ThinkPad Not Working with 10.10 update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8556/middle-button-on-thinkpad-not-working-with-10-10-update)

And put it in `/usr/share/...` and `/usr/lib...` neither seem to work. They USED to work. I used to be able to use that method of fixing it, but it seems in 11.04 this doesnt work?

I dont wanna give up on Ubuntu yet...

Comment: Which ThinkPad do you have? On my T510 both works fine: selecting 1-10 and wheele emulation (enabled using gpointing-device-settings).

Comment: I can confirm that everything work on my T410 as well. I used the manual method where we create a file in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/ as for the selection it also works for me. I understand you concern though, I cannot imagine living without my trackpoint! Do you have another distro installed where you can check if this is a problem with the hardware?

Comment: I have an L512...

Its like pointing devices just doesn't even work or me or something. Ill try one last try... maybe installs of Wubi are different?

Comment: WTF. the middle button timeout in the trackpoint settings in gpointing-device-settings was set in the middle and it made my left trackpoint button timeout?

Answer (score 2):

I got this to work.

First off, all the messed up settings were because gpointing-device-settings (or Pointing Devices in Ubuntu app screens) were set to button 4 in the TrackPoint device settings screen, when it should have been button 2. Once I changed it to button 2 all worked well.